# Adding a C compile flag to yocto build

Tags: yocto

I am trying to build ninvaders with yocto-nanbield. I had already built it with the same `.inc` and `.bb` files using two different previous yocto releases, sumo and dunfell. But as far as I understand they updated poky's gcc-arm and now I have to add `-fcommon` in order to compile ninvaders with yocto release nanbield. Given that the content of the two files is pretty simple and short, I share them here.

ninvaders.inc:

```
SUMMARY = "nInvaders is a Space Invaders clone based on ncurses for ASCII output."
HOMEPAGE = "https://ninvaders.sourceforge.net/"
SECTION = "Games"
SRC_URI = "${SOURCEFORGE_MIRROR}/${BPN}/${BPN}-${PV}.tar.gz"

DEPENDS = "ncurses (>= 5.2)"

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake CC="${CC}"
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 nInvaders ${D}${bindir}
}
```

ninvaders_0.1.1.bb:

```
require ninvaders.inc
LICENSE = "GPL-1.0-only"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://gpl.txt;md5=393a5ca445f6965873eca0259a17f833"
SRC_URI[md5sum] = "97b2c3fb082241ab5c56ab728522622b"
```

When I try to build it with `bitbake ninvaders` I see multiple definition errors like:

```
multiple definition of `skill_level'; aliens.o:(.bss+0x67c): first defined here
```

What I want to achieve is pretty simple and clear. Unfortunately I could not get it work. What I understand from the yocto manual is that I simply have to add `CFLAGS:append = " -fcommon"` in my `local.conf` file. I do it but still see the same multiple definition errors.

When I open the devshell with `bitbake -c devshell ninvaders` and add the flag in the Makefile it works. But this is obviously not the proper way to do it.

How do I have to append an extra C compile flag to my project? I also want to add this specific flag only for ninvaders. Instead, if I put it in local.conf I think I append the flag for the whole build. So I have put it in the .bb file but as it already had not work in local.conf, did not work also in the .bb file. How can I append this flag in a way that it is used only while building this specific package?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. As I already knew, it is pretty straight forward but the concept is not very easy to get used with it for a newbie. I simply modified ninvaders.inc as:

```
SUMMARY = "nInvaders is a Space Invaders clone based on ncurses for ASCII output."
HOMEPAGE = "https://ninvaders.sourceforge.net/"
SECTION = "Games"
SRC_URI = "${SOURCEFORGE_MIRROR}/${BPN}/${BPN}-${PV}.tar.gz"

DEPENDS = "ncurses (>= 5.2)"

EXTRA_CFLAGS = "-fcommon"

EXTRA_OEMAKE = "CC='${CC}' CFLAGS='${EXTRA_CFLAGS}'"

do_compile() {
    oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 nInvaders ${D}${bindir}
}
```

EXTRA_OEMAKE appends additional options to the original content of the Makefile.